# Multiple multi-line regex matches in Bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to do some fairly simple string parsing in bash script. 
Basically, I have a file that is comprised of multiple *multi-line* fields. Each field is surrounded by a known header and footer.

I want to extract each field separately into an array or similar, like this

```
>FILE=`cat file`
>REGEX="@#@#@#[\s\S]+?@#@#@"
> 
>if [[$FILE =~ $REGEX ]] then
>   echo $BASH_REMATCH
>fi
```

FILE:

```
@#@#@#################################
this is field one
@#@#@#
@#@#@#################################
this is field two
they can be any number of lines
@#@#@#
```

Now I'm pretty sure the problem is that bash doesn't match newlines with the "."

I can match this with "pcregrep -M", but of course the whole file is going to match. Can I get one match at a time from pcregrep?

I'm not opposed to using some inline perl or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have gawk

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="@#*#" }
NF{
    gsub("\n"," ") #remove this is you want to retain new lines
    print "-->"$0 
    # put to array
    arr[++d]=$0
} ' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
--> this is field one
--> this is field two they can be any number of lines
```

Comment: Modified this a little bit to do what I want. Awk is something I've never learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr) language performs whole-document multi-line matching, binds variables, and (with the `-B` "dump bindings" option) emits properly escaped shell variable assignments that can be `eval`-ed. Arrays are supported.

The `@` character is special so it has to be doubled up to match literally.

```
$ cat fields.txr
@(collect)
@@#@@#@@#################################
@  (collect)
@field
@  (until)
@@#@@#@@#
@  (end)
@  (cat field)@# <- catenate the fields together with a space separator by default
@(end)

$ txr -B fields.txr data
field[0]="this is field one"
field[1]="this is field two they can be any number of lines"

$ eval $(txr -B fields.txr data)
$ echo ${field[0]}
this is field one
$ echo ${field[1]}
this is field two they can be any number of lines
```

The `@field` syntax matches an entire line. These are collected into a list since it is inside a `@(collect)`, and the lists are collected into lists-of-lists because that is nested inside another `@(collect)`. The inner `@(cat field)` however, reduces the inner lists to a single string, so we end up with a list of strings.

This is "classic TXR": how it was originally designed and used, sparked by the idea:

> Why don't we make here-documents work backwards and do parsing from reams of text into variables?

This implicit emission of matched variables by default, in the shell syntax by default, continues to be a supported behavior even though the language has grown much more powerful, so there is less of a need to integrate with shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I would build something around `awk`. Here is a first proof of concept:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ f=0; fi="" }
    /^@#@#@#################################$/{ f=1 }
    /^@#@#@#$/{ f=0; print"Field:"fi; fi="" }
    { if(f==2)fi=fi"-"$0; if(f==1)f++ }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin="@#@#@#################################"
end="@#@#@#"
i=0
flag=0

while read -r line
do
    case $line in
        $begin)
            flag=1;;
        $end)
            ((i++))
            flag=0;;
        *)
            if [[ $flag == 1 ]]
            then
                array[i]+="$line"$'\n'    # retain the newline
            fi;;
     esac
done < datafile
```

If you want to keep the marker lines in the array elements, move the assignment statement (with its flag test) to the top of the `while` loop before the `case`.